# I need help returning the number of seconds between 2 months in UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, calendar, uilocalnotification

I succeeded to calculate the difference in seconds between two dates, however in case of months I used the generic 30 days for each which isn't true in several cases.
Is there a simpler way. I need that for the time interval in UILocalNotification

```
@IBAction func createNotificationButton(sender: UIButton) {

    //Prepare Local notification
    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let currentDateAndTimeComponents = NSDateComponents()

    let currentDateAndTime = NSDate()
    println("CurrentDateAndTime: \(currentDateAndTime)")

    //Determining current time NSDates components
    let currentDateAndTimeComponentsVariables = userCalendar.dateWithEra(9223372036854775807,  year: currentDateAndTimeComponents.year
        , month: currentDateAndTimeComponents.month, day: currentDateAndTimeComponents.day, hour: currentDateAndTimeComponents.hour, minute: currentDateAndTimeComponents.minute, second: currentDateAndTimeComponents.second, nanosecond: 0)


    println("\(currentDateAndTimeComponents.era)")

    //Check if the value in () should be changed
    //   let currentDateAndTime = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(currentDateAndTimeComponents)!

    // Notification future time
    let futureNotificationDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    futureNotificationDateComponents.era = 9223372036854775807
    futureNotificationDateComponents.year = yearTextField.text.toInt()!
    futureNotificationDateComponents.month = monthTextfield.text.toInt()!
    futureNotificationDateComponents.day = dayTextField.text.toInt()!
    futureNotificationDateComponents.hour = houtTextField.text.toInt()!
    futureNotificationDateComponents.minute = minuteTextField.text.toInt()!
    futureNotificationDateComponents.second = 0
    let futureNotificationDay = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(futureNotificationDateComponents)!

    let yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond: NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond




    let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond, fromDate: currentDateAndTime, toDate: futureNotificationDay, options: nil)
    println("Difference: \(difference)")
    println("Era : \(difference.era)")
    println("Year: \(difference.year)")
    println("Month: \(difference.month)")
    println("Day: \(difference.day)")
    println("Hour: \(difference.hour)")
    println("Minute: \(difference.minute)")
    println("Second: \(difference.second)")

    var timeInterval = difference.second + difference.minute*60 + difference.hour*3600
    timeInterval = timeInterval + difference.day*3600*24 + difference.month*30*3600*24
    timeInterval = timeInterval + difference.year*365*24*3600

    println("Time interval: \(timeInterval)")

    let newTimeInterval = Double(timeInterval)
    let test = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    println("Time zone: \(test)")

    func LocalNotificationFunction() -> UILocalNotification {

        //Preparing a local notification to alert for the need to play the video message
        let LocalNotificationMessage:String = "Hello \n\n It's time to prepare to play the video message from PosterityMessages"
        localNotificationOfVideo.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

        println("In the function: \(localNotificationOfVideo.timeZone)")

        localNotificationOfVideo.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: newTimeInterval)
        localNotificationOfVideo.alertBody = LocalNotificationMessage
        localNotificationOfVideo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        return localNotificationOfVideo

    }

    ScheduleLocalNotificationIfPossible()

}
```

Comment: It looks like the question title does not match what you want to accomplish. Is what you are trying got accomplish is togged the date two months from a date?

Comment: I just added   localNotificationOfVideo.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
userCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone() and it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the following two lines is that it will only give you the excess-second of a minute:

```
let yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond: NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond

let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond, fromDate: currentDateAndTime, toDate: futureNotificationDay, options: nil)
```

If you want to retrieve the actual seconds between two dates you have to specify that you only want to retrieve the seconds:

```
let yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond: NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond

let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond, fromDate: currentDateAndTime, toDate: futureNotificationDay, options: nil)
```

Same goes for month. If you merge Month and Second into one statement you will only get the excess-seconds for every month. It is quite hard to explain / understand. If you take the difference between now and in one hour you get 3600 seconds. If you take the difference between now and (next month in one hour) you still will get only 3600 seconds. Only if you omit the `Month` part you will retrieve the actual seconds.

Hope that helps. Do you need any more clarification? The code for month would be

```
let yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond: NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth 

let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(yearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond, fromDate: currentDateAndTime, toDate: futureNotificationDay, options: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks luk1202 that's right on the spot. Just have to find a way to adapt times to my own timezone. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just added   localNotificationOfVideo.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
        let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        userCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
        
and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a date two months in the future is wanted.

Using date components and incrementing the months component:

```
let startDate = NSDate()
println("startDate: \(startDate)") // "startDate: 2015-07-12 12:48:41 +0000"

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let units: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond
var components = calendar.components(units, fromDate: startDate)

components.month += 2
let futureDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
println("futureDate: \(futureDate!)") // "futureDate: 2015-09-12 12:47:29 +0000"
```